# DIV background image won't stay inside the div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `div` elements. One is named "profilen" where I want a background to be and have the same size as the other `div`, and keep the background in another `div` element named "profilbg" that is placed inside the div, but the background image is going outside the div.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
<style>
.profavataren {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.profuin {
    float: right;
    width: 350px;
    height: 175px;
    padding-top: 75px;
}
.leftcolum {
    border-style: none none solid none;
    padding: 0px;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.centercolum {
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    padding: 0px;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.rightcolum {
    border-style: none none solid none;
    padding: 0px;
    border-color: #000000;
    padding-left: 3px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.centerTable { margin: 0px auto; }
.profilen {
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}
.profilbg {
background: url(<?php echo $uin->backgroundimg; ?>);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
.profilsize {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
</style>
<div class="profilsize" align="center">
  <table width=100% cellspacing=0>
    <tr><td class="subTitle" ID="title" colspan="2"><b><font face="monbaiti" size="3" color="a1a1a1"><?php echo $uin->login; ?></font><?php echo $ledelsen; ?></b></td></tr>
  </table>

  <div class="profavataren">
    <img src="<?php echo $uin->avatar; ?>" height="250" width="250">
  </div>
  <div class="profuin">
    <div align="center" style="padding-left: 35px; padding-right: 35px;"> 
      <table align="center" class="centerTable">
        <tbody>
          <tr><td class="leftcolum">Brukernavn:</td><td class="centercolum">&nbsp;</td><td class="rightcolum"><?php echo $uin->login; ?></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="leftcolum">Status:</td><td class="centercolum">&nbsp;</td><td class="rightcolum"><?php echo $status; echo "($online)"; ?></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="leftcolum">Penger:</td><td class="centercolum">&nbsp;</td><td class="rightcolum"><?php echo $penger; ?></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="leftcolum">Brukernavn:</td><td class="centercolum">&nbsp;</td><td class="rightcolum"><?php echo $uin->login; ?></td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="profilen">
    <div class="profilbg">
      <?php echo nl2br($uin->profilen); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's the div I want it inside

```
<div class="profilen">
  <div class="profilbg">
    <?php echo nl2br($uin->profilen); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the background always sticks out off those `div` elements. If you take a look at this screenshot, you see the background image shouldn't be above the red line, as the div should be below that.

http://prntscr.com/ahslxw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use clear: both;

That should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

try and clear the float in your profilbg css

like this

```
.profilbg {
    background: url(<?php echo $uin->backgroundimg; ?>);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the other elements on the page are all floating, the background image will go behind them also. To fix this, make sure the "profilen" div **clears** the left and right floating elements above, so that when you add a background image, it will be below the floating elements. Therefore, change your CSS for "profilen" to:

```
.profilen {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.profilen {
    background: url(<?php echo $uin->backgroundimg; ?>);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height="250"
}
```

Comment: height: 250px; but when i tries that it just get above the red line and not below it, the image should only be below the red line :/

Comment: <div class="profilen">
  <?php echo nl2br($uin->profilen); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="profilbg">
  </div>